# Use of the can? method with a each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

When I read the documentation of cancan you can do something like this:

```
<% if can? :edit, @product %>
```

Now I have the following code and there it doesn't work.

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% if can? :sort, |product| %>
    MyButton
  <% end %>
```

How can I make sure this works as well?  What syntax do I need to use?  I hope I don't need to do a

```
@product = Product.find(|product|.id)
```

because that would clutter the views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you should pass to `can?` method `Product` instance, which is in `product` local variable, so:

```
<% @products.each do |product| %>
  <% if can? :sort, product %>
    MyButton
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```